# Type 'TableNames' cannot be used to index type 'TState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've ran into a problem indexing an object with known keys.

```
export function makePagers<
  TableNames extends string,
  TState = Record<TableNames, INumericPageParams>
>(initialState: TState) {
    ...
    function _usePager(name: TableNames) {
        const { state } = usePagerState();
        const pager = state[name]; <-- Here's the error
        return {
          numbers: { page: pager.page, per_page: pager.per_page },
          strings: { page: String(pager.page), per_page: String(pager.per_page)}
    };

  }
}
```

When I hover over the error I see ...

```
const state: TState = Record<TableNames, SwapType<IPageParams, string, number>>
Err: Type 'TableNames' cannot be used to index type 'TState'.ts(2536)
```

I'm confused by this since all types seem to be carried correctly and state should only have keys of type `TableNames`.

I'm on TypeScript 4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never said that `TState` is constrained to a record with keys from `TableNames`, so that is why indexing into `TState` is unsafe. You only specified that it should default to the record. Add a constraint to tell TypeScript that the keys must be `TableNames`:

```
export function makePagers<
  TableNames extends string,
  TState extends Record<TableNames, INumericPageParams> = Record<TableNames, INumericPageParams>
>(initialState: TState) {
```